# syntax error pulling git clone into python anywhere

Tags: git, pythonanywhere

I am trying to pull a clone into pythonanywhere.

I run:

```
git clone https://github.com/<your-github-username>/my-first-blog.git
```

I get the following syntax error:

```
 File < stdin>, line 1
    git clone https://github.com/yavorcik/my-first-blog.git
            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Not sure what I am doing wrong here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are issuing the command in one of the Python consoles, while you should issue it in a Bash console, thus the error message that this is not valid Python code.